# How to edit a specific line of text VB

Tags: vb.net

I was it so when I enable a check button, a certain line of text changes.
This is what I have so far:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    FileOpen(1, "C:\ServerMaker\Vanilla\server.properties", OpenMode.Output)
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        FileSystem.WriteLine("")
    End If
End Sub
```

I want the line 7 to change to the text "allow-flight=true" and if it is not checked, I want it to be "allow-flight=false"

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? Your question is too vague. Which line will change? The first line? Is this text in a Edit Box or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Because `true` and `false` have different length, you have to read all lines first. Then you can write the modified file:

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
'Read the current contents
Using file = System.IO.File.OpenText("server.properties")
    While Not file.EndOfStream
        lines.Add(file.ReadLine)
    End While
End Using
'Write the modified contents
Using file As New StreamWriter("server.properties")
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        If i = 6 Then
            file.WriteLine("allow-flight=" & IIf(CheckBox1.Checked, "true", "false"))
        Else
            file.WriteLine(lines(i))
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

The check `If i = 6` should probably be `If lines(i).StartsWith("allow-flight=")` to allow the line to be somewhere else.

Comment: @user2792832 If the answer helped you, you may accept and / or upvote it. That applies to your other questions as well.